# JSTree: Make node expand when single clicked instead of double click?

Tags: jstree

I can't figure this out for the life of me but I am trying to configure my JSTree to override the double click event so it is just single click event. Is this something added to the callback configuration? I am not sure how to do this, will I need to edit the JSTree source code? Documentation here: http://docs.planbleu.org/modules/webportal/jquery/jsTree.v.0.9.5/documentation/#configuration

I tried changing the "ondblclk" to "click" in the source code and then adding a "click" callback option to the config settings and it did nothing... I am probably doing it wrong though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sending this into the tree creation function did the trick:

```
   onselect: function(n, t) {
         t.toggle_branch(n);
    },
```

(where t is the reference to the tree)

Comment: Where is this meant to be added? Could you please share the entire tree creation function?

Answer (score 7):

I found the correct answer in an issue for the plugin on github.  The above answers do NOT work.  This absolutely works and is a comprehensive answer on how to call the plugin, and how to make it use single-click expand instead of double-click.

```
    $('#jstree')
        .on('click', '.jstree-anchor', function (e) {
            $(this).jstree(true).toggle_node(e.target);
        })
        .jstree()
```

[Here is a link to where the author mentions the solution](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/953), in case you need it.

Comment: This is the only solution which works!

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#tree").bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
 $("#tree").jstree("toggle_node", data.rslt.obj);
 $("#tree").jstree("deselect_node", data.rslt.obj);
});
```

This might get you started in the right direction. You'll probably need to filter out which ones to expand or not depending on meta data.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $fullIndex.on('select_node.jstree', function(e, data){
    data.instance.toggle_node(data.selected);
  })
  .jstree()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#your_id_where_Tree").on('select_node.jstree', function(e, data){
       data.instance.toggle_node(data.selected);
 });
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!